# os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, unity-game-engine, xcode10

os/c-api/il2cpp-config-platforms.h' file not found
I have this error when I build the project, using a device. I checked the path out and it is right, I see the file there (UnityExport/Libraries/libil2cpp/include/os/c-api/il2cpp-config-api-platforms.h) but the error is still occurring.
Any help?

Thank you.

Comment: please check your path in Unity.xcconfig file is correct.

Comment: Yes, I did and is correct but the error is still occurring.

Answer (score 0):

I also had similar error. Add -DRUNTIME_IL2CPP=1 in Project's Build Setting's ->Other C flags and C++ Flags. Some developers suggest it works, if not,  if u find solution please share

Comment: I also face same issue, some  version of Xcode, this works. But for me it didn't if u find solution please share..

Comment: Did you find any solution for same issue? i am facing same issue.

Comment: @user3247895, watch this video, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLkeGz5vCzk&t=85s

Comment: There are so many things in video. I don't know exactly which step will solve my issue. I am using https://medium.com/@IronEqual/how-to-embed-a-unity-game-into-an-ios-native-swift-app-772a0b65c82 for unity integration. My xocde version is 11.2. My unity version is 2019.2.17